# kotlin list of Pair into list of Pair.first

Tags: list, kotlin

I'm trying to get used to the idioms and shortcuts in Kotlin and I'm wondering if there was any way to do this.

```
val pairList = listOf(Pair(1, 2), Pair(5, 10), Pair(12, 15))
val firstList = // should be [1, 5, 12]
```

Or in general, any class with any one of their member variables. I currently have:

```
val pairList = listOf(Pair(1, 2), Pair(5, 10), Pair(12, 15))
val firstList = ArrayList<Int>()
pairList.forEach { firstList.add(it.first) }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is: `val firstList = pairList.map { it.first }`

`first` represents the 1st member of the pair, and of course there is `second` for the 2nd member

The same `firstList` be generalized for:

```
val pairList = listOf(Pair(ClassA(), ClassB()), Pair(ClassA(), ClassB()), Pair(ClassA(), ClassB()))
```